# Very large standard errors and no Cis with multilevel mixed-effects logistic regression results

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, confidence-interval, random-effects-model

I am running multilevel mixed-effects logistic regression analyses and for some of the random effects parameters it reports very large standard errors relative to the estimate, and in some cases it does not report confidence intervals at all. **Why might the analyses report results like these, and should I be concerned?** And and all help is well appreciated.

I am doing this in STATA using the `meqrlogit` command.

Here is an example of the code:

```
meqrlogit pass chair_position rm_position subchair_position subrm_position spon_distfrommedian offmaj seniority oncommittee openrule cong110 || bill_id: comm_hetero commdiffchammed
```

Here are example results:

```
Refining starting values: 

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -726.56332  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -719.01611  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -719.01611  (backed up)

Performing gradient-based optimization: 

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -719.01611  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -716.93212  (not concave)
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -716.54788  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood =  -716.2483  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -716.21564  
Iteration 5:   log likelihood = -716.17671  
Iteration 6:   log likelihood = -716.17426  
Iteration 7:   log likelihood = -716.16639  
Iteration 8:   log likelihood = -716.16635  

Mixed-effects logistic regression               Number of obs      =      2127
Group variable: bill_id                         Number of groups   =       166

                                            Obs per group: min =         1
                                                           avg =      12.8
                                                           max =        86

Integration points =   7                        Wald chi2(10)      =    555.00
Log likelihood = -716.16635                     Prob > chi2        =    0.0000

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           pass |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     chair_position |   2.881085   .2225479    12.95   0.000     2.444899    3.317271
        rm_position |   .6765902   .1774423     3.81   0.000     .3288097    1.024371
   subchair_position|   1.938028   .1143659    16.95   0.000     1.713875    2.162181
     subrm_position |    .852036   .1639464     5.20   0.000      .530707    1.173365
spon_distfrommedian |  -3.158594   .4516214    -6.99   0.000    -4.043756   -2.273432
             offmaj |  -1.354971    .286989    -4.72   0.000    -1.917459   -.7924832
          seniority |   .0153654   .0183937     0.84   0.404    -.0206857    .0514164
        oncommittee |  -.7430332   .1834081    -4.05   0.000    -1.102507   -.3835599
           openrule |  -1.031346    .191665    -5.38   0.000    -1.407002   -.6556893
            cong110 |   .1220945   .1919112     0.64   0.525    -.2540445    .4982336
              _cons |   3.325638   .4520586     7.36   0.000      2.43962    4.211657
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Random-effects Parameters  |   Estimate   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
bill_id: Independent         |
                sd(comm_h~o) |   .0001571   1.890037             0           .
                sd(commdi~d) |   5.06e-09   1.057652             0           .
                   sd(_cons) |   .5151542    .133236      .3103046    .8552366
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test vs. logistic regression:     chi2(3) =     8.92   Prob > chi2 = 0.0303

Note: LR test is conservative and provided only for reference.
Note: log-likelihood calculations are based on the Laplacian approximation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not overly familiar with Stata, but the section that says

`Obs per group: min =         1`

is probably the culprit. If you only have 1 or 2 observations in a group, then the error will be massive, and calculating a confidence interval is mathematically impossible (in general, there may be ways around it).

Basically, some of your groups have sample sizes that are too low to result in precise estimates.

Comment: Thanks Conor. A follow-up question: Does having group sizes that small make it unreasonable to run a multi-level mixed effects model?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'unreasonable', and by what you actually want to infer from your model. Personally, I would (probably) still use the model, but I would be vary careful about making specific inferences about the groups with low sample sizes. So whether you use the model will be dependent on what hypotheses you plan to test